# Can't connect to SVN in Windows installed via Bootcamp

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I have installed Windows 7 Ultimate on my MacBook Pro via Bootcamp. I have Windows Support drivers installed and everything is working fine. But I am unable to connect to SVN. I tried checking out through NetBeans, Tortoise SVN, Eclipse and many other programs, but no help. Before Windows 7, I had Windows 8 installed on my MacBook and I was getting the same error. Is anybody familiar with such sort of problem and possibly have a solution?

Comment: *I was getting the same error* - what is the exact error you get?

Comment: Hi @ivanJovovic I have answered my own question, but I am not sure if that's going to resolve your problem. Unfortunately I can't remember the very exact error I was getting in my Netbeans, but it was like: No information available for svn+ssh://... Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Our SVN Repository only allows specific IP addresses to checkout projects. That IP address is supposed to be a part of "hosts" file in Windows/System32/Drivers/etc folder. I chucked the IP address in "hosts" file and it's working perfectly fine.